# filtrando fechas

Tags: ms-access, delphi

estoy haciendo un programa que filtra fechas de tres tablas de mi base de datos,el problema es cuando realizo una búsqueda solo me muestra una tabla y no las tres tablas que yo deseo.Este es mi código

```
query.Close;
 query.SQL.Clear;
 query.SQL.Text := ('select campo1,campo2 from tabla1 where campo3 >= :fecha1 and campo3 <= :fecha2 '+ ' union all '+
 'select campo1,campo2 from tabla2 where campo3 >= :fecha1 and campo3 <= :fecha2 '+ 'union all '+   'select campo1,campo2 from tabla3 where campo3 >= :fecha1 and campo3 <= :fecha2 order by coberturafechahasta ');
 query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha1').Value:= FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',Datetimepicker1.Date);
 query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha2').Value:= FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',Datetimepicker2.Date);
query.Open;
```

uso componenetes ado y MS ACCESS como base de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En algunos componentes de conexión, si necesitas utilizar varias veces el mismo parámetro debes usar nombres diferentes. 
En el código que has puesto quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
  query.Close;
  query.SQL.Clear;
  query.SQL.Text := ('select campo1,campo2 from tabla1 where campo3 >= :fecha1 and campo3 <= :fecha2 '  + ' union all '+
                     'select campo1,campo2 from tabla2 where campo3 >= :fecha3 and campo3 <= :fecha4 '+ 'union all '+
                     'select campo1,campo2 from tabla3 where campo3 >= :fecha5 and campo3 <= :fecha6');
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha1').Value := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',edtFechaIni.Date);
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha3').Value := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',edtFechaIni.Date);
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha5').Value := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',edtFechaIni.Date);

  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha2').Value := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',edtFechaFin.Date);
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha4').Value := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',edtFechaFin.Date);
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha6').Value := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',edtFechaFin.Date);
  query.Open;
```

No especificas cuales estás utilizando, así que debes probarlo con tu código. Por ejemplo con ADO, la forma correcta de urilizarlo es así.

Comment: justo lo que necesitaba. Gracias

Comment: @pablo. Si te sirvió la respuesta, márcala como correcta, para que sirva de ayuda a futuros usuarios, por favor. Y así se queda la pregunta cerrada.